# Lipschitz functions are compact or not?

Tags: functional-analysis

For a constant $\alpha,\lambda$ I want to determine whether $K=\{f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}: |f(x)-f(y)|\le \lambda|x-y|^\alpha\}$ in fuctions space with suprimum norm($\|f\|=\sup_{x\in [a,b]}{f(x)}$) is compact or not. I proved that $K$ isn't bounded. Please tell me is the prove true or not. Is it enough to say $K$ is not complete?
`Thanks for your helps.`
source: Analysis for Applied Mathematics written by Ward Cheney.(Page:350,Problem:4)

Comment: you probably need to specify in which space / in which topology

Comment: You were right. I edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a standard result that a compact subset of a metric space is bounded.

It is also not hard to prove: Pick any fixed $x$, and write $B(x,r)$ for the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. Then if $K$ is compact, $$K\subseteq\bigcup_r B(x,r),$$ so these balls form an open cover of $K$. Thus a finite number of them cover $K$, and you're done.

Alternatively, if $K$ is unbounded, pick $x_n\in K$ with $d(x,x_n)>n$ and check that then the sequence $(x_n)$ has no convergent subsequence.